# How to slice if the header and index both are int in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

The index and header are both int. How slice df by index name and header name?

```
       2001 2002    2003
50425   139  140    136
50434   122  121    131
50514   128  125    177
50527   127  129    154
50603   128  120    169
50618   124  126    123
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [174]: df.loc[50434:50600, 2002:2003]
Out[174]:
       2002  2003
50434   121   131
50514   125   177
50527   129   154
```

in case you have strings as column names:

```
In [177]: df.columns
Out[177]: Index(['2001', '2002', '2003'], dtype='object')
#                ^    ^  ^    ^  ^    ^

In [178]: df.loc[50434:50600, '2002':'2003']
Out[178]:
       2002  2003
50434   121   131
50514   125   177
```